# How to perform performance testing for webappication

Tags: java, web-applications, performance-testing

I have a java web application deployed in tomcat. I am very new to automated testing.Our intention is to create a bench mark for our search page as below:

**Time to load search results for 100 users at a time with simple search criteria to complex criteria, via login to the application from 100 browser instances.**

can you suggest the best way/tool to achieve it. I heard about selenium and selenium Grid to incorporate parallel execution. Is this the right way.
Welcome your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You are looking for load testing

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your test with `selenium`, but there is more convenient task for performance measurement of java applications (including web apps)..
Try *Apache* *JMeter* http://jmeter.apache.org/